# HTML in MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, html, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am a new in Xcode and i was working with mail app which uses MFMailComposeViewController. I wanted to design my *messageBody with HTML. Actually its a small "BOOK A MEETING" app. So I wanted to put date and time feild so that user could choose date and time. But when i run my app, i cannot enter anything in my date and time feild. Here is my code. Hope i could get some help.

```
 - (IBAction)BookAMeeting:(id)sender {
    //email subject
    NSString *emailTitle = @"Haven Support";
    //email content
    NSMutableString *messageBody = [NSMutableString string];


    [messageBody appendString:@"<h1>Please Enter the following feilds to book a meeting.</h1>\n"];
    [messageBody appendString:@"<form>NAME: <input type = 'text' name='fname'> \n <br>TIME: <input type = 'time' name='timee'><br>\n DATE: <input type = 'date' name='date'><br>"];

    //to address
    NSArray *toRecipents = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"xyz@hotmail.com"];

    MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
    mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mc setSubject:emailTitle];
    [mc setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:YES];
    [mc setToRecipients:toRecipents];

    //present mail view controller on screen
    [self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:NULL];

    }
```

Comment: Why are you trying to put an HTML form in an email message? What's your goal?

Comment: @rmaddy because i wanted to let the users select the date and time before they can send email regarding "booking a meeting". I wonder if that is possible or not

Comment: No. You write code (user interface) to get the values you want. You don't get user input via email. If anything, you can send an email that include the data the user chose through the app, but you can't get input via email.

Comment: @rmaddy thank you for clearing my confusion as i am new in xcode. Can u suggest me some idea how a user can select their date and time if its okay for u. thanks

Comment: That's way to broad of a question for a comment. Do some research and try some code. When you get stuck on something specific, post a question specific to that issue. Enjoy.

Comment: i totally understand..thanks for clearing my confusion though. Good day !